# How to change font size in a formattable table in R

Tags: r, fonts, size, formattable

I am using formattable package in R to make a KPI table with icons and conditional colors. I need to export the file as a png so I am not using it in the Rmarkdown environment.

I didn't find any information on formattable document to say how to change font size, some answers online explored changing font type by embedding the formattable code in html. However, due to my limitation of exporting as an image file, I would like to know if there's just a command I can put in the code to make the whole table fonts bigger.

```r
KPI<-formattable(d, align='c',
list(A=formatter("span",style=x~ifelse(x>0,"green","red")))
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any CSS styles avaiable to "span" tag:

```
library(formattable)


conditional_font_size <- formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ ifelse(x > 5, "font-size:20px; color:red","font-size:10px; color:blue")
)

formattable(
    iris,
    list(
        Sepal.Length = conditional_font_size
    )
)
```

[image]

To add CSS for headers:

```
temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
table_html <- paste("<div><style>th{color:green;}</style>",as.character(ftable),"</div>")
writeLines(table_html,temp_file)
rstudioapi::viewer(temp_file)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So I was able to change all the column content with font size of my choice now. But is it possible to change the title row as well?

Comment: Where do you want to view the table. Since there is not built-in way to change header CSS in `formattable`. It will be a little tricky to view it in the viewer pane if you want to change the header CSS. But it's much easier if you view it using RMarkdown or RShiny.

Comment: I see. I am piecing images together into a PDF, but unfortunately cannot utilize RMarkdown/RShiny for this project. Thanks for letting me know though!

Comment: I already updated my answer. Even though it's a little tricky, but it's still doable. The way to do it is to convert `formattable` objects into plain text, and add CSS for headers. Finally, read the html file in rstudio viewer pane

Comment: May I ask how to change only dataframe's header's font size?